# Can you initiate a phone call in Google Assistant on a smart speaker?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

Phone calls are rolling out in the US for Google home (not through a mobile device).
Can a Google Assistant agent initiate such a phone call? (I'm fine with the Agent terminating at this point, and if it will have a prompt that the users needs to approve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, you can't. Making features available for developers seems to lag by at least several months at this point. But hopefully Google is listening to the features that we, as developers, are looking for.